# is it possible to detect an ANR after it happenned?

Tags: android

Is it possible on the client side to know if an ANR had happened in the previous launches of the app?

For example, a user used an app for 10 days, on the 10th day an ANR happened and the app was shutdown, on the 11th day the user opened the app again, is it possible to know at that point that the app had an ANR issue in any point of its lifetime on the current device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Android 11 and higher, you can call `getHistoricalProcessExitReasons()` on `ActivityManager` to find out about pass process terminations, including ANRs.

```kotlin
val reasons =
  context.getSystemService(ActivityManager::class.java)?.getHistoricalProcessExitReasons(null, 0, 0).orEmpty()
```

`reasons` will be a `List<ApplicationExitInfo>`. The `reason` property on an `ApplicationExitInfo` is an `Int` that maps to a series of constants on `ApplicationExitInfo`... such as `ApplicationExitInfo.REASON_ANR`, meaning that a previous process had been terminated due to an ANR.

Comment: I'm not able to find any resources about `ApplicationExitInfo`. Does it work if user doesn't exit the app via ANR dialog or app crashes? Are we able to get ANR even if user is not prompted with a dialog? [This ANR](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230950647?pli=1) is very generic and Firebase doesn't offer anything.

Comment: "I'm not able to find any resources about ApplicationExitInfo" -- there is [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo). I also wrote about it in [this section](https://commonsware.com/R/pages/chap-dataaccess-002) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/R). "Does it work if user doesn't exit the app via ANR dialog or app crashes? " -- see the JavaDocs for a list of `REASON_` codes. "Are we able to get ANR even if user is not prompted with a dialog" -- I do not think a dialog appears if you are in the background.

Comment: Official resource are as always nearly useless with no information about how to use it and makes sense of importance, stack trace. Article you wrote is quite helpful. Yeah, it doesn't. My question was about this generic ANR that might occur of any reason without any trace. I'm not able to track it as i get from your response with ApplicationExitInfo it won't be possible to get root source if user didn't kill the app or ANR dialog is not promted since it's displayed as on background on crashlytics.

Comment: @Thracian: I do not know if `REASON_ANR` will be used for a backgrounded app tying up the main application thread. You could write a scrap app that ties up the main application thread in the background, and see what you get!